# Implementing Audio chat with Socket.IO and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, webrtc

I have created a chat application using `sails.js` (`node.js`) and `socket.IO`.

I need to implement `audio chat` and `file transfers` along with it.

Could anyone help me in getting basic tutorial links for integrating `WebRTC` with `socket.IO`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you to licsence you code? I am in the need of the same thing now, and I don't want to go through planning -> development -> testing -> from scratch for such a robust thing

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If I were you, I would use a WebRTC library providing both the client and the server side. Check [EasyRTC](http://easyrtc.com/), [SimpleWebRTC](https://simplewebrtc.com/), [PeerJS](http://peerjs.com/) or others. Most libraries are implemented in Javascript and run in Node.js.

You will find tutorials in their respective websites.

I personally use PeerJS, the code and documentation are both very good, and it fully supports data channels (useful for file transfer). The only thing is that there are only 2 founders, and the community seems quite small.

Comment: WebRTC has limited support for IE and Safari. So how to go about this issue ?

Comment: Can video and audio chat be implemented without WebRTC ?

Comment: Safari and Edge have better support now. Who cares about IE? Given Flash is officially dead now, I suppose WebRTC is the only cross platform solution in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It seems to me that WebRTC is the way to go for video and audio chat.

Answer (score 0):

I am also planning to make your kind of app on nodejs. During my research I found that WEBRTC support for mobile browsers is limited. In todays world whenever we are building a Web app we consider that a major portion of our users are going to use it on mobile phone. WebRtc is supported on android browsers like chrome, Firefox and opera. But on iPhone it doesn't support safari nor windows phone browsers.
You should take a look at Wowza streaming cloud at https://www.wowza.com/docs/wowza-streaming-cloud-free-trial